# Find non-trivial groups $G, H$ such that $G \cong H \times G$

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

This is question II.3.4 from Aluffi's algebra 0.

Let $G, H$ be groups and assume that $G \cong H \times G$. Can you conclude that $H$ is trivial?

The hint already states this is not the case. I think the group should be infinite. So, I have tried doing several things with the real numbers both additive and multiplicative and a small group such as $\{1, -1\}$, but I have not been able to find a bijective homomorphism in this way.

Comment: hint: what happens if you take the product of $H\times H\times H\times\dots$ with $H$?

Comment: Hmm, I am not sure if the product of an infinite amount groups is again a group, but I suppose I cannot see any reason why it would not be. In that case it is quite easy yes.

Comment: @Yadeses Just endow the product group with obvious operation $(a_1, a_2, \dots) + (b_1, b_2, \dots) = (a_1+b_1, a_2+b_2, \dots)$. It is immediate to see that it is a group.

Answer (score 3):

Let $H$ be the additive group of the field $\mathbb F_2$ (i.e. the only group up to isomorphism with 2 elements) and $G = \oplus_{i-1}^\infty H$ be the infinite product group composed of countable copies of $H$.

Then $G \cong H \times G$.

Comment: $H$ can be replaced with any nontrivial group here. This sort of thing is sometimes known as the "Eilenberg swindle." Fundamentally we are making use of the bijection $\mathbb{N} \cong \mathbb{N} \sqcup 1$ in the "exponents."